# "No EmacSQL SQLite binary available" while running Org-Roam on GUIX

Tags: org-roam, clang, sqlite

I'm struggling to set up Org-Roam on a minimal GUIX set-up. There is an attempt to compile `Compiling EmacSQL SQL binary` which throws an error `No EmacSQL SQLite binary available`. I have installed both gcc and clang and the correct path (ie. the same as is returned by `which gcc`) is found using eg. `(executable-find "clang")` (the code tries gcc before clang so I have tried removing the former with the same results). With apologies, I am typing out a couple of lines of the *Backtrace* as my GUIX is a very minimal writing set-up but the first two lines are the following:

```
error("No EmacSQL SQLite binary available, aborting")
emacsql-sqlite-ensure-binary()
```

This error is thrown by, for example, running `(org-roam-node-find)` The *Backtrace* shows a call to `make-instance(emacsql-sqlite-connection :file "~/.emacs.d/org-roam.db")` followed by a number of calls such as `apply(#f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode [...])(#<emacs-sqlite-connection emacsql-sqlite-connection-[...]> (:file "~/.emacs.d/org-roam.db"))`.

A file named emacsql-sqlite.elc (7.4k) exists in a directory in `.emacs.d/elpa/emacsql-sqlite-20230118.2015`. Another directory exists in `.emacs.d/elpa/ named emacsql-20230118.2020.` These directories are repopulated upon running `(org-roam-node-find)` when they are deleted or moved.

Internet searches have thrown up problems with Windows and Mac OS all of which appear to be resolved by installing gcc or clang.

Comment: You should install the `sqlite3` package using your distro's package manager. This is not an Emacs problem.

Comment: It is installed. Typing `sqlite3` in eshell takes me to a SQL prompt, typing `which sqlite3` gives me its location, and executing `(executable-find "sqlite3")` in the \*scratch\* buffer gives me the same location.

Comment: If you look at *how* `emacsql-sqlite-ensure-binary` tries to find the binary, it does `(file-exists-p emacsql-sqlite-executable)` - so you have to set `emacsql-sqlite-executable` to the full path of the binary you found above. In particular, it is *not* using `executable-find`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP checked that the `sqlite3` binary *is* installed on his system and can be found by shells and through the `executable-find` mechanism. But the `emacs-sqlite` package uses `emacsql-sqlite-ensure-binary` (as the error message shows) and that uses its own mechanism:

```el
;;; Ensure the SQLite binary is available

(defun emacsql-sqlite-ensure-binary ()
  "Ensure the EmacSQL SQLite binary is available, signaling an error if not."
  (unless (file-exists-p emacsql-sqlite-executable)
    ;; try compiling at the last minute
    (unless (ignore-errors (emacsql-sqlite-compile 2))
      (error "No EmacSQL SQLite binary available, aborting"))))
```

So the variable `emacsql-sqlite-executable` has to be set to the full path of the `sqlite3` executable for this to work. Add the setting to the init file:

```el
(setq emacsql-sqlite-executable "/path/to/sqlite3")
```

Comment: This is useful and I expected it to resolve the issue but it doesn't. Not yet. I'm picking this apart in \*scratch\*. `(file-exists-p emacsql-sqlite-executable)` reports true here but appears to evaluate as false in emacsql-sqlite.el. In the Scratch buffer, `(emacsql-sqlite-ensure-binary)` returns nil. I may try the guix irc or something here and will return to answer below if something turns up.

Comment: Check to see what the `(emacsql-sqlite-compile 2)` call does: if it fails, then dig into that functions to see *why* it fails.

Comment: IOW, it's not that `file-exists-p` that returns different things in the two contexts (it's hard to imagine how that would happen). Instead, it's that `emacsql-sqlite-ensure-binary` fails because the *other* function that it calls (i.e. `emacsql-sqlite-compile`) fails.

Comment: Apologies for taking some time to mark this correct.. It gave me what I needed to debug this problem. The Guix set-up is intentionally a minimal writing set-up I tend to run offline and being variously neurodivergent I tend to be contextually either here or there.. I intended to document my debugging process but it's now a long time ago. From memory it related to misspellings of variables such as, I presume, emacsql-sqlite-executable.